# JSP Page not loading jquery correctly - but jquery file gets delivered

Tags: jquery

I have setup Tomcat 7 on Windows and writing a simple jsp that outputs some HTML.
I wanted to do a auto-update by loading content from another jsp with jquery.

I can see in firebug that jquery is loaded as the GET-Request is successfull and the content looks fine.

Anyhow, firebug tells me

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined $( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
```

which is really confusing currently.

The index.jsp uses the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
        <head>
            <title>Demo</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/load_statistic.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
            <div class="top_left">
                <h1>Statistic</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="top_right">
                 <img src="images/logo.png" width="285" height="105"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="load_statistic">
            <%@ include file="statisticdata.jsp" %>
            </div>
```

and load_statistic javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                    function ()
                    {
                    $('#load_statistic').load('statisticdata.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
                    }, 5000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
                               //every 5000 milliseconds(10sec)
                               });
```

And as the error message is telling, jquery does not seem to get loaded correctly. There must be some error but I can't figure out what.

Comment: tried replacing all $ with jQuery??

Comment: replacing $ with jQuery does not solve the issue. The Reference error refers then to 'jQuery'

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the final, generated html?

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your script tags.

```
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/load_statistic.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: closing the script tags is not the problem (though your suggesstion would be standard conform). anyhow it does not solve the question :(

Comment: Really? I pasted your markup, tried running, and it failed. Then closed tags & it ran as expected. Are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: yes I am sure - I can't figure out any problem this is totally crazy. But it must be something "similar simple" like that ...

Comment: Try a protocol relative url? //code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: I have now redeployed several times, did things like adding the closed tags, checking every path etc. and now it seems to work. *maybe* it was a deployment error I have not seen or a combination of simple things - i don't know. it is now working..

Comment: Subtle bugs happen. :)